# How to have a transient field as key of a map in hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, hibernate-mapping

I need to have a Map of items but the item that I need to make 'key' is transient and hibernate is not able to make that a 'key'. How can I do it?

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "rela.city", 
                         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cityId")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "rela.person", 
                         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "rela.social", 
                         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "code")) })
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RelationshipId rela = new RelationshipId();

    @Transient
    public String getCode(){
         return rela.getSocial().geCode();
    }
    ....
}

@Entity
public class City implements java.io.Serializable {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
               mappedBy = "rela.city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "code")
    Map<String, Person> People = new HashMap<>();
    ....
}
```

As you can see I want to make code the key of the map but it does not work as code is transient.

Comment: Have you tried `@MapKey(name="rela.social.code")`?

Comment: @JBNizet yes did not work

Comment: How it would be a key if it is not persisted?

Comment: @AleksandrM it would be the key of the map not primary key of the table, another thing is all cityId, id and code exist in db.

Comment: *If a persistent field or property other than the primary key is used as a map key then it is expected to have a uniqueness constraint associated with it.*